# Scripting an APPX install

Tags: windows-10, powershell, installation, vbscript

I have a very large application which installs two of its many components from APPX files which have been renamed to an ADIX extension. The rest of the components are a mixture of MSI/MST and EXE installations. I'm trying to script the entire install from VBScript.

Opening the ADIX files with 7Zip shows they contain a VFS folder under which is ProgramFilesX64\VendorName\AppName and all the files/folders to be installed are under there.

If I rename the files to the APPX extension then I can run that manually and the files install to C:\Program Files\WindowsApps. However the applications installer sends the files directly to C:\Program Files\VendorName\AppName but there is no documentation for how that is done.

I would like to install these components with something like the PowerShell Add-AppxPackage command.

Comment: Please show us the script you have so far.

Comment: vbscript doesn't have any real interface with appx. Your best bet is just `wscript.shell`, and launch powershell with a command like `Add-AppxPackage -Path "c:\path\to\file.adix"`. You can also use c# instead, but I don't know if that's any easier in vbs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404663/7411885

Comment: The main question is how to get the files redirected to the desired location.

Comment: According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66200353/windows-store-appx-package-install-file-in-different-location) APPX files can only go to WindowsApps folder but somehow the default installer for this application is changing the destination folder.

Comment: @FJones yes, windows only installs appx/msix packages into appx volumes (view your local volume(s) with `Get-AppxVolume` in case your installer is creating its own). Are you sure the adix files are installed as appx packages and not just getting extracted to /program files/? Does it get registered as an app? (`Get-AppxPackage | select Name,InstallLocation`)

Comment: Thanks for the response, tried both commands, got only the standard volume, did not show up as an installed package. I believe this application stores installed MSI's and ADIX packages in a custom database under ProgramData. All MSIs are set as SystemComponent so as not to show up as installed items and then custom entries are added to the registry for a customized uninstaller. There is a patch, just a new ADIX file with a whole new set of files including 4 missing and 4 new so I think it simply removes the previous and installs the new. Everything is done by an adix handler dll, undocumented.

Comment: After the install a custom program registers some of the files which are .NET assemblies. Possibly confirms that the ADIX is a glorified ZIP file extraction.